# 'end' expected to close if - lua

Tags: lua, openwrt, expected-exception

I have the following code as part of a [LuCI](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac) web interface for an application I am making for [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/). I am getting an error which says it is expecting an "end" to close an if statement but I cannot see any statements which have not been closed correctly.

Any help would be apprciated!

Error:

```
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:448: Failed to execute firstchild dispatcher target for entry '/admin/network/amld'.
The called action terminated with an exception:
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:448: Failed to execute cbi dispatcher target for entry '/admin/network/amld/amld_status'.
The called action terminated with an exception:
/usr/lib/lua/luci/cbi.lua:75: /usr/lib/lua/luci/model/cbi/amld/amld_status.lua:122: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 78) near '<eof>'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:448: in function 'dispatch'
    /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:195: in function </usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:194>
```

My Code:

```
local fs = require "nixio.fs"
local sys = require "luci.sys"
local uci = require "luci.model.uci".cursor()

registered_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "registered")
m = Map("amld_cbi", translate("amld"))
if registered_s == "true" then

    s = m:section(TypedSection, "amld_conf", "Status")

    fqdn = s:option(DummyValue, "fqdn", "concentrator")

    local updown = s:option( Button, "_updown", translate("Start / Stop") )
    updown._state = false
    function updown.cbid(self, section)
        local pid = fs.readfile("/var/run/amld.pid")
        self._state = pid and #pid > 0 and sys.process.signal(pid, 0)
        self.option = self._state and "stop" or "start"
        return AbstractValue.cbid(self, section)
    end
    function updown.cfgvalue(self,section)
        self.title = self._state and "stop" or "start"
        self.inputstyle = self._state and "reset" or "reload"
    end
    function updown.write(self,section,value)
        if self.option == "stop" then
            luci.sys.call("killall -HUP amld")
        else
            args = build_run_time_args()
            luci.sys.call("amld " .. args)
        end
    end

elseif registered_s == "false" then

    s = m:section(TypedSection, "amld_conf", "Register amld")

    username = d:option(Value, "username","Username");username.optional=false;
    password = d:option(Value, "password","Password");password.optional=false;

    m.on_after_commit = function(self) -- Make sure this doesn't get called if registered = true
        register_device()
end

function build_run_time_args()
    local args = ""

    username_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "username")
    if username_s ~= nil and username_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -u " .. username_s .. " "
    end

    password_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "password")
    if password_s ~= nil and password_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -p " .. password_s .. " "
    end

    passphrase_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "passphrase")
    if passphrase_s ~= nil and passphrase_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -P " .. passphrase_s .. " "
    end

    tun_dev_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "tun_dev")
    if tun_dev_s ~= nil and tun_dev_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -t " .. tun_dev_s .. " "
    end

    interface_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "interface")
    if interface_s ~= nil and interface_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -i " .. interface_s .. " "
    end

    gateway_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "gateway")
    if gateway_s ~= nil and gateway_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -g " .. gateway_s .. " "
    end

    cacert_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "cacert")
    if cacert_s ~= nil and cacert_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " -C " .. cacert_s .. " "
    end

    test_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "test")
    if test_s ~= nil and test_s == "1" then
        args = args .. " -T "
    end

    foreground_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "foreground")
    if foreground_s ~= nil and foreground_s == "1" then
        args = args .. " -f "
    end

    debug_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "debug")
    if debug_s ~= nil and debug_s == "1" then
        args = args .. " -x "
    end

    bundle_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "bundle")
    if bundle_s ~= nil and bundle_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " " .. bundle_s .. " "
    end

    fqdn_s = uci.get("amld_cbi", "amld", "fqdn")
    if fqdn_s ~= nil and fqdn_s ~= "" then
        args = args .. " " .. fqdn_s .. " "
    end

    sysconf_s = io.open("/etc/config/amld.sysconf", "r")
    if sysconf_s ~= nil then
        args = args .. " -s " .. " /etc/config/amld.sysconf "   
        io.close(sysconf_s)
    end
    return args
end

function register_device()

    --run aml in test mode, if success, set registered, else ...?
    uci.set("amld_cbi", "amld", "registered", "true")
end

return m
```

Comment: Why don't you try the usual technique of removing stuff until it works?

Comment: I have been trying, the problem is that the OS is command line only and everytime you update the source for the interface you have to restart which is a waste of time / frustrating.

I have a feeling the problem is `if registered_s == "true" then` because that is when I have been getting all the trouble.

Comment: It seems to me that an `end` shoud be added just before `build_run_time_args`. The `end` that is there closed the function being assigned to `on_after_commit`.

Comment: Ah thank you @lhf! Would you care to post that an answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Comment: It is a programming question and the solution is to correct the syntax, how is that off-topic?

Comment: @Tom: you don't need to fix the problem on the remote machine. Copy that single file to your desktop computer and use lua/luac to compile it. It's a syntax error, not a run time error, so you don't need the other libraries to actually be installed on your desktop. Really, it won't be practical for you to "bother" us for every syntax error you're going to have in this application you're making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that an `end` shoud be added just before `build_run_time_args`. The `end` that is there closed the function being assigned to `on_after_commit`.